# Efibootmgr reports that NVRAM is full - how do I add a new ESP?

Tags: linux, uefi

I believe I know what the problem is, and I know of one more thing I could try to fix it, though I am aware that it is possibly dangerous, so I should ask here first.
I have personally installed Linux multiple times before, and run it as my main OS, though I've never encountered a problem like this.

### The problem

I am helping a friend install Manjaro on an old laptop (alongside Windows 7 as a dual-boot setup) (I believe it is a Samsung Notebook NP-R580H). This issue is not specific to Manjaro though (we've checked plain Arch Linux as well, and I assume it applies to any operating system we will try to install).

On our first attempt everything was going fine until it attempted to install GRUB, which failed. GRUB complained that the ESP did not look like an EFI partition, saying: `/boot/efi doesn't look like an efi partition`.

This was only a small issue, because after formatting the ESP from NTFS to vFAT, GRUB recognised it as a valid ESP. We did backup the contents of the ESP before formatting it (so we have the original Windows 7 EFI files), though I did not take note of the UUID (because it seemed entirely pointless at the time).

Unfortunately GRUB returned a new error, which brings us to today: `Failed to create EFI Boot variable entry: No space left on device`.
After a lot of research, I figured that the NVRAM was reporting that it is full, so efibootmgr was unable to create a new boot entry.

I assumed that we would be able to list the boot entries using `efibootmgr -v`, but it complains saying that `No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery`. After some more research, it seems like these boot entries may only be visible if a bootable file is at a known location - which of course there *isn't*, because the ESP was reformatted (this is according to https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#Default/fallback_boot_path).
After this discovery, we tried adding a UEFI boot entry using efibootmgr directly, but with the same error.

### Possibilities

At this point I can think of 1 option if we cannot properly read the NVRAM: using the kernel parameter `efi_no_storage_paranoia`, as suggested at https://askubuntu.com/a/1073318, though I'm worried about that. What if that bricks the laptop entirely?

In the process of writing this I discovered that the `bcfg` tool could help (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#bcfg), though I'll wait for the opinions of those who are more experienced than me before doing anything else.

At this point I'm just looking for a way to restore original ESP. I imagine if I could read the old values from NVRAM I would know the UUID I need to use to recreate the ESP, though I haven't been able to get those values yet.

If any more information is needed, I will do my best to supply it.

Comment: Running out of disk space in the ESP and running out of NVRAM space are two very  different issues.  A ESP requires a specific GUID (not a UUID!), i.e.  C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware they're different things. I believe this is a problem with the NVRAM being filled up (or so it seems), not the ESP (since we formatted that).
I didn't know that there was any difference between a GUID and a UUID though. I'll look into that.

Comment: NVRAM can fill up for a number of reasons.  Can you boot to an EFI shell prompt?

Comment: I believe we can boot into an EFI shell, though it may be a day or more before I can test that and run any commands.